# Pulling from an array in a Mongo document by date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to pull from an array in a mongo document using a value by comparing an isodate string older than 60 days using a mongo query, but it is not pulling the data from the array in the document. For example the document below should only have job 3 remaining in logs array after the query runs, but all three are remaining currently.

document

```
{
    "_id" : "0jYHGDtEIaE3BCjBW",
    "owner" : "a",
    "logs" : [ 
        {
            "job" : "1",
            "createdAt" : "2020-01-31T05:07:09.468Z"
        }, 
        {
            "job" : "2",
            "createdAt" : "2020-01-31T05:07:11.119Z"
        },
        {
            "job" : "3",
            "createdAt" : "2021-04-01T05:07:11.119Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

code

```
let deleteDate = new Date(Date.now() - 60 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    Logs.update(
      {},
      {
        $pull: {
          logs: {
            createdAt: {
              $gte: deleteDate,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      { multi: true }
    );
```

expected result

```
{
    "_id" : "0jYHGDtEIaE3BCjBW",
    "owner" : "a",
    "logs" : [
        {
            "job" : "3",
            "createdAt" : "2021-04-01T05:07:11.119Z"
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `createdAt` field in collection is it string type or date type?

Comment: @turivishal its a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few fixes,

- `createdAt` type is string in collection and `new Date` will return date type so condition will always false, you have to change same type in both side either its string or date,
- for solution you can use `toISOString()` after `new Date` function to convert date type to string
- i think you are using wrong conditional operator `$gte`, it should be `$lte`

Your final query would be,

```
let deleteDate = new Date(Date.now() - 60 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString();
Logs.update(
  {},
  {
    $pull: {
      logs: {
        createdAt: {
          $lte: deleteDate
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { multi: true }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-H-0dr9FhKm)